# Can you paraphrase using "rather?"

Tags: would-rather

Can you say:

> "The new one-way system is considered by most rather to be an impediment than a help."

using "rather" to mean

> "The new one-way system is considered by most to be more of an impediment than a help?"

Answer (score 1):

Your original sentence is almost there, but "rather" is in the wrong place. Try this:

> The new one-way system is considered by most to be an impediment **rather than** a help.